# my player can fly for some reason, i have gravity on the rigidbody of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

Im trying to make a 3d game with unity, but i dont know how to implement gravity, so i turned gravity for the rigidbody on. Also how could i implement jumping and wallrunning into this code?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float playerHeight = 2f;

    public float moveSpeed = 6f;

    float horizontalMovement;
    float verticalMovement;

    Vector3 moveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    bool isGrounded;

    private void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight / 2 + 0.01f);

        print (isGrounded);
       MyInput();
       
    }

    void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalMovement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = transform.forward * verticalMovement + transform.right * horizontalMovement;
    }  

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    } 

    void MovePlayer()
    {
        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `transform.forward` or `transform.right` ever point upwards? Also instead of `normalized` you will rather want to use `Vector3.ClampMagnitude` .. using normalize is wrong if your input values can result in magnitude smaller then 1 .. e.g. for a Vector with magnitude close to `0` it might lead to unexpected behavior